# Too high level of nesting while implementing SQL INTERSECT in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, yii

One of my last works is Yii based hardware catalog. Each item can be linked with a lot of groups.

```
CREATE TABLE item_group (
id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
itemId INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
groupId INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Only that itemIds have to be shown which have all of groupIds selected by user.  And here goes my buggy solution:

```
$groups = isset($_GET['groups']) ? array_merge(array_diff($_GET['groups'], array('0'=>'-')),array()) : array();
$sql = '';
$brackets = '';
$groupMaxKey = count($groups) - 1;
//some code here
for($i=0;$i<=$groupMaxKey;$i++){
    $sql .= "SELECT itemId FROM item_group WHERE groupId='".$groups[$i]."' ";
    if($i != $groupMaxKey){
        $sql .= "AND itemId IN (";
        $brackets .= ")";
    } else {
        $sql .= $brackets;
    }
}
```

I found out that maximum level of nesting is 32. More groups give an error. What will be the cleanest solution for this?

To clarify here an example of query:

```
SELECT itemId FROM item_group 
WHERE groupId='31' AND itemId IN (
    SELECT itemId FROM item_group 
    WHERE groupId='24' AND itemId IN (
        SELECT itemId FROM item_group 
        WHERE groupId='35'
    )
)
```

////
Answer really works:

```
SELECT g1.itemId 
FROM ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((( item_group g1 
INNER JOIN item_group g2 ON g1.itemId = g2.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g3 ON g1.itemId = g3.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g4 ON g1.itemId = g4.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g5 ON g1.itemId = g5.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g6 ON g1.itemId = g6.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g7 ON g1.itemId = g7.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g8 ON g1.itemId = g8.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g9 ON g1.itemId = g9.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g10 ON g1.itemId = g10.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g11 ON g1.itemId = g11.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g12 ON g1.itemId = g12.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g13 ON g1.itemId = g13.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g14 ON g1.itemId = g14.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g15 ON g1.itemId = g15.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g16 ON g1.itemId = g16.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g17 ON g1.itemId = g17.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g18 ON g1.itemId = g18.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g19 ON g1.itemId = g19.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g20 ON g1.itemId = g20.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g21 ON g1.itemId = g21.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g22 ON g1.itemId = g22.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g23 ON g1.itemId = g23.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g24 ON g1.itemId = g24.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g25 ON g1.itemId = g25.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g26 ON g1.itemId = g26.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g27 ON g1.itemId = g27.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g28 ON g1.itemId = g28.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g29 ON g1.itemId = g29.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g30 ON g1.itemId = g30.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g31 ON g1.itemId = g31.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g32 ON g1.itemId = g32.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g33 ON g1.itemId = g33.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g34 ON g1.itemId = g34.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g35 ON g1.itemId = g35.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g36 ON g1.itemId = g36.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g37 ON g1.itemId = g37.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g38 ON g1.itemId = g38.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g39 ON g1.itemId = g39.itemId)
INNER JOIN item_group g40 ON g1.itemId = g40.itemId)
WHERE g1.groupId='1' AND g2.groupId='2' AND g3.groupId='3' AND g4.groupId='4' AND g5.groupId='5' AND g6.groupId='6' AND g7.groupId='7' AND g8.groupId='8' AND g9.groupId='9' AND g10.groupId='10' AND g11.groupId='11' AND g12.groupId='12' AND g13.groupId='13' AND g14.groupId='14' AND g15.groupId='15' AND g16.groupId='16' AND g17.groupId='17' AND g18.groupId='18' AND g19.groupId='19' AND g20.groupId='20' AND g21.groupId='21' AND g22.groupId='22' AND g23.groupId='23' AND g24.groupId='24' AND g25.groupId='25' AND g26.groupId='26' AND g27.groupId='27' AND g28.groupId='28' AND g29.groupId='29' AND g30.groupId='30' AND g31.groupId='31' AND g32.groupId='32' AND g33.groupId='33' AND g34.groupId='34' AND g35.groupId='35' AND g36.groupId='36' AND g37.groupId='37' AND g38.groupId='38' AND g39.groupId='39' AND g40.groupId='40'
```

Comment: How come you used Drewch's solution but accepted hackattack's? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using INNER JOINs. There is no reason to nest these statements.

Any example of a proper query for your example case would be:

```sql
SELECT g1.itemId 
FROM (( item_group g1 
        INNER JOIN item_group g2 ON g1.itemId = g2.itemId)
        INNER JOIN item_group g3 ON g1.itemId = g3.itemId) 
WHERE g1.groupId='31' AND g2.groupId='24' AND g3.groupId='35'
```

I've tested this on a simple table with the three columns `(id, itemId, groupId)` and it works. It is very easy to put this kind of statement in a loop, and there is no maximum on the number of joins.

To make this run faster, you should index the `itemId` column in your `item_group` table.

You can do this with the following SQL statement:

```sql
ALTER TABLE item_group ADD INDEX ( itemId )
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you, if you add the index's it will be very fast. I would suggest also adding an index for groupId.

Comment: I'll try to answer how fast both solutions when my website filled with products. Think this helps a lot of people to make right choise

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this problem right, it appears you are trying to find the intersection of itemIds in different groups?

What we can do is count up all the itemIds that are in the groups we are looking at...

```
SELECT itemId, COUNT(groupId) as CNT
FROM item_group
WHERE groupId IN (*GROUP_IDS*)
GROUP BY itemId
```

Now, as long as an item can not be in the same group twice, we can just pull the rows out of this query whos CNT equals the number
of groups we are looking at...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT itemId, COUNT(groupId) as CNT
    FROM item_group
    WHERE groupId IN (*GROUP_IDS*)
    GROUP BY itemId
) as TMP WHERE CNT = *NUMBER_OF_GROUP_IDS*
```

And that should do it.

Comment: your answer also works and now it looks better if prevent duplicated rows while creating relations. am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure what performs better, my solution or the inner joins. That is an interesting question in itself. In my opinion, The more compact the SQL is, the easier it is to understand. Sometimes readability is more valuable then performance.